# Get my database value as a string to pass it to my javascript function PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function, mysqli

I have an string value from my database which is the **id** and I have a button with a javascript function **onclick="values('argument')**".

My problem is that when i tried to click on that button i have this error:

```
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: argument is not defined
```

I know this happens because the argument is not treat as a string.

How can I pass the argument as a string?

All this is a table which is contained in a php function that shows info from my database

This is my complete code.

```
    <?php


   function oportunities($resultQuery)
   {

    echo '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="responstable">
                    <thead class="thead">

                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>value1</th>
                        <th>value2</th>
                        <th>value3</th>
                        <th>value4</th>
                        <th>value5</th>
                        <th>value6</th>
                        <th>value7</th>
                        <th>value8</th>
                        <th>value9</th>
                        <th>value10</th>
                        <th>value11</th>
                        <th>value12</th>
                        <th>value13</th>
                        <th>value14</th>
                        <th>value15</th>
                    </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

    foreach($resultQuery as $row){
        echo '<tr>
                <td> '. $row['id'] .'</td>
                        <td>'. $row['value1'] .'</td>
                        <td>'.  $row['value2'] .'</td>
                        <td class="descripcion">
                            <p class="text-descripcion">'.$row['value3'].' </p>
                        </td>
                        <td> '.$row['value4'].' </td>
                        <td> '. $row['value5'].' </td>
                        <td><p class="text-center">'. $row['value6'] .'% </p></td>
                        <td> '.$row['value7'].' </td>
                        <td> '.$row['value8'].' </td>
                        <td> '.$row['value9'].' </td>
                        <td> '.$row['value10'].'</td>
                        <td> '.$row['value11'].' </td>
                        <td> '.$row['value12'].' </td>
                        <td> '. $row['value13'].' </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="center-block btn btn-acept"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="values('. $row['id']. ')" class="center-block btn btn-editar launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-edit"><i
                                    class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                </tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>
        </table>
       </div>';
}
```

Comment: The error is javascript, where is your javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add quotes, and escape them

```
<button onclick="values(\''. $row['id']. '\')" class="center-block
```

As you're using doublequotes for the attribute, you'll need singlequotes for the argument, but you're already using singlequotes in PHP, so you have to escape them so they aren't parsed by PHP.

Of course, the better option would be to not use inline javascript at all, but `addEventListener`.

Comment: but if I use addEventListener how can I pass the  $row['id'] argument to the javascript function?

Comment: Using a data attribute to put the data in the element, and getting that data attribute when the button is clicked.

Comment: May you please explain it with a example?

Comment: I got this error      jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Not sure why you would get a jQuery error when the posted code doesn't use jQuery? Anyway, the elements have to be available to get them, note that the script is placed after the element with the given ID etc.

Comment: Actually I'm using jquery and ajax, this php function that I post is a echo that shows the info table when a row is updated

Comment: Anyway I dont know why is that happening, but i use the onclick="values(\''. $row['id']. '\')" version Thank you so much.